# How to move row from one sheet to another based on value in Column P

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with a header.  In column P, I have a column of percentages.  Anything over 150%, I want to move that entire row over to a new worksheet called "Groups".

I don't have much code right now because I tried about 5 different ways and wound up deleting my work. :/

Comment: this is a one time thing? or an ongoing operation you want to do? Do they need to disappear from the first tab? or just "copy" to the other tab?

Comment: This is part of a script that I run from a custom menu.

I would like to delete the lines from the current sheet.

Comment: In your 5 attempts, did you manage to locate the rows that meet your criteria? Did you manage to copy the values in those rows? If so, did you manage to append the values to the other sheet? Was the problem that you could not delete the rows afterwards? What errors did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to copy the information from the columns to another spreadsheet you can try this:

```
function copyToSheet() {
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var rows = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  for(var i=0; i< rows.length; i++)
  {
    if(rows[i][2]>150)
    {
      targetSheet.appendRow(rows[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

The script takes the information from the source sheet and then compares the data from column C for each row and if the value is higher than 150 it copies the whole row to a different sheet.

This is my sample data in Sheet1:

[image]

Here is the result in Sheet2 after running the script:

[image]

You can adapt the script depending of your needs.

Answer (score -1):

If you have some AppScript experience, this may help:

1. sort range by percent column descending;
2. find first row with percent below 150%;
3. Get values from range rows 2 to that row minus 1;
4. Delete rows 2 through that row minus 1;
5. set values to other tab with range starting at getLastRow()